# PHP HTML mail is not working as I wanted

Tags: php, html, gmail, sendmail

I have created reset password page, where used enters hes email, and PHP sends him back a the reset key. Mail works, but its going as plain text in my gmail account. I wanted it to go in HTML.

```
$subject = "Your password reset for {$config['site_name']}";

$message = "<html><body>";

$message .= "<p>Someone on" . $config['site_domain'] . "tried to reset your password.</p>";
$message .= "<p>Please click below link, if you want to reset your password.</p>";

$message .= "<p><a href='" . $config['site_url'] . "/forgot_password.php?key=" . $key . "'>" . $config['site_url'] . "/forgot_password.php?key=" . $key . "</a></p>";


$message .= "<p>Thank you,<br>The Admin - " . $config['site_url'] . " </p>";

$message .= "</body></html>";

// Create email headers             
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";

// Additional headers
//$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $config['site_name'] . " <noreply@" . $config['site_domain'] . "> \r\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender: <noreply@" . $config['site_domain'] . "> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <noreply@" . $config['site_domain'] . "> \r\n";

mail($input['email'],$subject,$message,$headers);

//update pw_reset field into DATABASE
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE members SET pw_reset = ? WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $key, $input['email']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: What about with other email providers?

Comment: Personally I like `Zend_Mail`.  Does everything I need done.

Comment: I like phpmailer for this kind of thing. It handles generating multipart email messages automatically. If you use plain mail() then you have to write the headers and delimiters yourself :P (and you do need to do multipart, since you don't want to send HTML email to someone who's only set up to get plain text).

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your headers like this:

```
$headers = 'From: You <you@example.com>' . "\n"; 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Notice that the From is before the MIME and Content and only Content ends with "\r\n", the other are just "\n".

[**Source**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) (saganwebdesign)

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. returns true on success

```
function sendMail($email, $subject, $message)
{
    $supportEmail = 'support@abc.com';
    $from = 'Test Application';
    $msg  = $message;
    $from = str_replace(' ', '-', $from);
    $frm  = $from.' <'.$supportEmail.'>';
    preg_match("<(.*)@(.*\..*)>", $frm, $match);

    ///////////////////Headers/////////////////
    $hdr='';
    $hdr.='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\n";
    $hdr.='content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\n";
    $hdr.="From: {$frm}\n";
    $hdr.="Reply-To: {$frm}\n";
    $hdr.="Message-ID: <".time()."@{$match[2]}>\n";
    $hdr.='X-Mailer: PHP v'.phpversion();
    $x=@mail($email, $subject, $msg, $hdr);
    if($x==0)
    {
        $email=str_replace('@','\@', $email);
        $hdr=str_replace('@','\@',$hdr);
        $x=@mail($email, $subject, $msg, $hdr);
    }
    return $x;
}
```